# How do I sum up the long sides of all rectangles in a layer?

Tags: scripting, autocad, autolisp

Using AutoLISP (to be used for AutoCAD 2015), I am working on a script that calculates the total length of all rectangles that are placed on a certain layer.

(Concrete purpose: I have a layer with multiple rectangles representing the wooden beams intended to carry a wooden floor. I want to calculate how many metres of beams I will have to buy for this floor.)

What I have, so far, is a script that calculates the sum of the length of all lines on the layer. This works fine so far. It returns both the overall length of the (circumference) lines of all rectangles on the layer, and the number of rectangles found.

```
(defun C:PLINELEN (/ ent sset obj len sum layer a)
  (setvar "ERRNO" 0)
  (while
  (and (not (setq ent (car (entsel "Select object on layer: "))))
  (/= (getvar "ERRNO") 52)
  )
  )
  (cond ((and ent
    (setq sset
    (ssget
     "X"
    (list '(0 . "LWPOLYLINE")
    (cons 8 (setq layer (cdr (assoc 8 (entget ent)))))
  )
  )
  )
  )
  (setq a 0
    sum 0
  )

  (repeat (sslength sset)
          (setq obj (vlax-ename->vla-object (ssname sset a))
           len (vlax-curve-getDistAtParam
           obj
                 (- (vlax-curve-getEndParam obj)
                    (vlax-curve-getStartParam obj)
                 )
               )
           sum (+ sum len)
          )
          (setq a (1+ a))
  )

 (princ (strcat "\nTotal length of "
           (itoa a)
           (if (= a 1)
           " pline on layer "
           " plines on layer "
         )
         layer
         ": "
         (rtos sum)
 )
)
)
(T (princ "\nNo plines found"))
)
(princ)
)
```

What is missing yet is functionality to leave aside all the *short* sides of the rectangles, and sum up only the *long* sides.

For my understanding, the simplest solution would be: add functionality to determine the sum of the length of all *short* sides of the rectangles found on the layer, and then subtract it from "sum")

In pseudocode:

```
(iterate through all rectangles on the layer 
    (measure all four sides of the rectangle)
    (compare the four measurements and store [one of the] shortest into variable x)
    (sumOfShortSides = sumOfShortSides + x)
)
```

I am most of the way there, but I need a pointers to improve my existing code to drop the short sides.  Other solutions are also welcome.

How do I sum up the long sides of all rectangles in a layer?

Comment: That's not the way it goes, you need to start on your own, set up some code, then ask here if there is something you can't handle. Could you edit question and show a small sample of you tried already ?

Comment: Okay, I will post it as soon as I have it. (Will take some hours, I suppose.)

Comment: Experimental script added to the question.

Comment: On request of the supervising board, I have reformulated the question, narrowing down its scope to one specific topic.

Comment: There isn't any "supervising board" here, just regular users doing question review, to maintain a high quality level of questions. "We" do this by flagging questions as not appropriate, or asking OP to edit question. FIY, I didn't flag it, just tagged as "requires editing". See http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions . But you did indeed add some code, so should be ok now.

Comment: I know that my question is not one of the most ideal ones here, as there is more than one unsolved issue in it. Actually I am just trying to get a (first) grip on AutoLISP scripting for AutoCAD. As I have done in earlier posts in this forum, I will eventually present a well-documented final solution, as soon as I have it. Meanwhile, for paving the way to this solution, every helpful suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using rectangles, why not create a dynamic block with a stretch action that sets the length.  This way, you could just iterate all blocks on the required layer with the correct name and query for the dynamic length property.

Yes, this is a possibly huge change in your drafting procedure but it would provide you with what you need.